# Spring support for Maven2 WebApps

Tags: spring-mvc, maven

I can create a minimal web application by using the maven-archetype-webapp .

Now I want to make my webapp Spring-Web-MVC powered.

Can I directly modify my POM, and how?

What's the best practices for the folder structure, and so on?

Can you show me a spring web mvc archetype, or a hello world example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STS (Spring Source Tool Suite) ships with the Spring Template Project, this project wizard will create a simple Spring MVC webapp + maven support.

Hope this helps

You can refer the step-by-step instructions, under the below link.
http://webapptutorials.wordpress.com/category/spring-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

Maven [Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) document describes in great detail how web application should be structured using Maven. [Here](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/books) you'll find my simple Spring MVC showcase (REST-oriented).

Of course you are allowed to modify `pom.xml` (if the file is so complicated that users are afraid to modify it, then there must be something wrong with Maven...)

The only Spring-specific convention is to place general `applicationContext.xml` file under `/WEB-INF` - but this can be easily overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look using [appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) to bootstrap your spring-mvc application.